# PHPExcel xlsx to csv vlookup values displaying as #REF

Tags: phpexcel, vlookup

When converting xlsx files to csv using PHPExcel, vlookup values between multiple worksheets are not pulling through to the csv file (display as #REF!). Most common calcs pull through with an issue, but not vlookup.

Any suggestions? Here is the code I am using:

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($sread);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fpath);
$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->setDelimiter("|x3x3x3x|");
$objWriter->setEnclosure("\"");

$sloop = 1;

//SHEET LOOP
foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) { 
$tablex =   $trackid."_".$sloop;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($loadedSheetName);
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

$objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
$objWriter->save("files/".$loadedSheetName.".csv");

//LOAD DATA INTO DB HERE

$sloop++;
} //END OF SHEET LOOP
```

Comment: What is the actual vlookup formula, and the data it runs against. I know (for example) that vlookup doesn't work correctly with locale texts (Work Item #18772 - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/18772) or if it contains row or column ranges rather than explicit cell ranges

Comment: Mark, appreciate the response. The vlookup formula looks like this: "=VLOOKUP(A2,survey_results_all!$A$1:$Q$3935,17,FALSE)" - the vlookup formula references a different sheet.